# How to remove white screen while loading android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android. I have a web view which loads a URL. The problem is that after I open the application there is a white screen for 2-3 seconds after that the web view‘s URL is loaded.

I think this is the time the application Initiates.  How can I remove the white screen and display my Logo for that time? 
I heard of splash screen but in that the logo appears for 1 second then white screen appears for another 2-3 seconds and then finally the web view is loaded.

What am I doing wrong? Is it splash screen or some other way to display the logo while web view loads?

```
package com.exampe.dating;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/mobile/index.php");
         WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

splashActivity.java

```
package com.exampe.dating;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

       private static String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getName();
       private static long SLEEP_TIME = 10;    // Sleep for some time

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
          this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar

          setContentView(R.layout.splash);

          // Start timer and launch main activity
          IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
          launcher.start();
       }

       private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
          @Override
          /**
           * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
           */
          public void run() {
             try {
                // Sleeping
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
             }

             // Start main activity
             Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
             SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
             SplashActivity.this.finish();
          }
       }
    }
```

androidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exampe.dating"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
         android:name=".SplashActivity">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.exampe.dating.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you are using to show a splash screen and to load the web view.

Comment: @TedHopp : So sorry , forgot to update it here. Please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very weird to have two launch activities declared in your manifest like that. You should eliminate the intent filter for `SplashActivity` and just start `SplashActivity` from within `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`:

**EDIT** Updated to replace sleeping with waiting. Splash screen will disappear when the page is loaded or when a time-out occurs, whichever comes first.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static Object SPLASH_LOCK = new Object();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/mobile/index.php");
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
    }
    . . .
}

// in your WebViewClient:
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    synchronized (SPLASH_LOCK) {
        SPLASH_LOCK.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Then in `SplashActivity`, wait the delay you want and just call `finish()`. You don't need to start `MainActivity` again, because it's sitting behind the `SplashActivity` and will appear when `SplashActivity` finishes.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

       private static String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getName();
       private static long MAX_SPLASH_TIME = 10000;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          . . .

          setContentView(R.layout.splash);

          new Thread() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  synchronized (MainActivity.SPLASH_LOCK) {
                      // wait for notify or time-out
                      try { MainActivity.SPLASH_LOCK.wait(MAX_SPLASH_TIME); }
                      catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
                  }
                  finish();
              }
          }.start();
       }
       . . .
}
```

Note that you don't need the `IntentLauncher` class.

P.S. You didn't ask about this, but if you add this to the `SplashActivity` tag in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

then you don't need to call `requestWindowFeature` or set window flags in `onCreate`.

Comment: I minimised the time to `SLEEP_TIME = 1; `

so after 1 second the White screen appears for 2-3 seconds. 
Is there a way in which I dont have to specify the sleep time ? because the time taken to load may vary form devices to devices ? Am I right ?

Comment: @AdiMathur - You can try [Nicklas's trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569087/535871) of using `onPageFinished`. That call-back occurs in your `MainActivity` so you need a way to communicate it to the `SpashActivity`. The easiest way, I think, is to use a static lock variable. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep` in `SplashActivity`, synchronize and then wait on the lock object. When the page is finished, synchronize and call `notifyAll()` on the lock object.

Comment: If you're ever in Ontario I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: In slow internet if I follow this method, the app is crashing

Comment: @Reaching-Out - When the app crashes, what's the stack trace?

Comment: @Ted Hopp It's not showing any error but the activity is starting once again.

Answer (score 2):

Now you are showing a splash, sleeping and then dismissing the splash at the same time as  launching the mainactivity which is turn start to load the page.
Splash->Sleep->Launch & dismiss Splash -> loading of page

You should start to load the page whilst the splash is showing and remove the splash when the page has loaded.

You can override the

```
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
```

of the **WebViewClient** that is connected to your **WebView** and make that method dismiss the splash.
It is probably easier to have the splash as a Dialog instead of a activity also.