# Android app onStartup - White screen

Tags: android, android-theme

The well known issue of onStartup white screen appears with my app too (only since yesterday), but am unable to resolve with any suggestion as read in following threads:

1. [How to remove the white screen while my app loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940392/how-to-remove-the-white-screen-while-my-app-loads)
2. [How to remove white screen while loading android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568610/how-to-remove-white-screen-while-loading-android-application)
3. [Android - Prevent white screen at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437037/android-prevent-white-screen-at-startup?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [How To fix white screen on app Start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up)
5. [Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

and few more.

Not just onStartup, there are also some intermittent white screen for 5-10 seconds in between. This is happening both with build and release build.

Following is the code I'm using:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainPlayer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.blynq.app.services.BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

This issue was not there until yesterday. Have not update Android Studio too since yesterday. Currently I am using Android Studio 2.1.1.

In dire need for a solution, would be greatly thankful for help of any sort in this regard ?

Comment: Could be this issue which is easily solvable : http://stackoverflow.com/q/36575229/4252352

Comment: Do you have any commits that you can roll back to and compare code differences against, or is this literally no codes changes, just acting differently?

Comment: I have added youtube fragments and that is all. Sadly, this time I did not use GIT :/

Comment: Did you work on real device or on a emulator?

Comment: Same bug is appearing on both emulator and real device

Comment: @jay I'd save the state of the project as it is now (so you always have this to go back to), then undo the changes you made before this started happening, clean/rebuild project, uninstall the apk, reinstall, see if the problem is solved - if so work incrementally forward, testing until the problem occurs - only way I can think that you can narrow the problem down.